# View vote count button on mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, vote-count

On the mobile site, can there be a button directly below the vote up/down buttons for viewing vote counts? When I am using the mobile site and I want to view vote counts, I have to switch to the full site to do it which is very inconvenient.

It could be a small link that says "vote counts," because I don't know what the button would be (the letter "V?" a "+/-" thing? I have no idea).

Related: [Show the number of up-votes and down-votes on the mobile site theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/show-the-number-of-up-votes-and-down-votes-on-the-mobile-site-theme) , but I am requesting an additional button below the vote buttons. That way you won't accidentally click a vote button.

Comment: I've been wondering if I should ask this for a long time and well you did, before I did! I miss that functionality so bad when using mobile

Comment: @HugoDozois I've been meaning to ask this for a while too `:)`

Answer (score -2):

This was made possible from an [update to the mobile Android app in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222844/187194).   As of 2019 this still works, although it hasn't been implemented yet for the mobile version of SE.

Unconfirmed if iOS also works the same way or not.

Comment: Not relevant. Question asks for the mobile web version of the site which runs using a browser, not about the apps.

Comment: @Shadow Actually relevant, considering questions asked about the same feature for mobile apps have been closed and marked duplicate, referencing this question.

Comment: There was one closed as dupe of that one, I removed the android app tag from it.