# View number of 'Up' and 'Down' Votes of a question/answer - Android App

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

This feature is missing in Android App and this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/show-the-number-of-up-votes-and-down-votes-on-the-mobile-site-theme) is same but in general (Mobile web).

Additionally, once this feature is implemented, we might accidentally hit the 'Up' or 'Down' vote (In smaller devices). The author might wonder why their post got downvoted.

Comment: This is by far the most common reason for me going into desktop mode while browsing SO on mobile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of version 1.0.16 coming out in the next few days this has been fixed. If you're viewing a question on a community in which you have earned the privilege required to do this, you can long-tap on the entire area showing the current vote count and buttons to view the specific counts in a pop-up window.

Comment: Nice! :-D This is a feature that's still absent in the mobile site, and I'm pleasantly surprised that it's now in the app