# Can't see the vote count of a post in a private beta site

Tags: bug, android-app, private-beta, vote-count

I currently have the privilege of viewing up votes and down votes on both Stack Overflow and Portuguese Stack Exchange. However, I cannot view these votes specifically on PT.SE posts from the Android app (version 1.0.68). There appears to be nothing wrong with seeing vote counts on SO or Meta SO:

[image]

For PT.SE, only [100 reputation](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) is required to see the vote counts (I have 874 rep at the time of writing), and there is no problem with the feature when using a browser.

[image]

However, long-pressing the vote count on PT.SE posts does nothing. This sounds like a bug in the mobile application. Can it be that the app was hard-coded to Stack Overflow's [reputation requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)?

Comment: I never knew that you could view vote counts on the Android app, glad to know that I can just long tap them now.

Comment: @KevinBrown http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196839/view-number-of-up-and-down-votes-of-a-question-answer-android-app

Comment: I think the check is done on the app side which (wrongly) assumes it's always 1000 reputation required to view vote count. The API either does not expose "does this user have this privilege" feature, or the app isn't using it.

Comment: [Fixed for the iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279829/viewing-vote-counts-does-not-work-in-ios-app-for-private-beta-sites).

Comment: It seems that I can no longer reproduce, but it could be because I now have 1000+ rep in PT.SE.