# Viewing vote counts does not work in iOS App for private beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, private-beta, vote-count

In [Documentation](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com), Established User is awarded at 100 reputation. (since it's a private beta.)

A user should be able to view vote counts, however, this does not work in the Stack Exchange App (iOS, not sure about Android) when long pressing the question score.

Is this because the App is programmed to show vote counts only at 1000 reputation which is the reputation required to be awarded this privilege for all other sites?

Just want to know the reason. I don't think it's a pressing issue to be fixed since only Documentation Beta awards this privilege at 100.

---

**Long pressing this does not show upvote/ downvotes**

[image]

Comment: I... don't think that, as a feature, exists in the app at all regardless of the site. (Although if Docs beta is the only site affected, technically it affects every private beta.)

Comment: @Adam It does, long pressing the vote count will show the number of upvotes and downvotes, it's detailed in the iOS App Tour

Comment: Oh, there it is. I tried it out before commenting, but I guess I pressed wrong. :)

Comment: No repro here - works fine on Docs beta (now that I know what I'm doing :)). Having said that, I have a diamond, so maybe that messes with the privilege check. In other words, I'm no help at all. Hopefully Brian Nickel can shed some light on what's going on here.

Comment: @Adam I think that it's because you have met the 1000 reputation requirement

Comment: Diamond trumps all rep checks, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Could be either.

Comment: @Adam It might be. Just to check, are you able to view vote counts in a community that you have less than 1000 rep?

Comment: Viewing vote counts is hit and miss for me in the app. Sometimes it works, other times it doesn't.

Comment: Nope. Sounds like it probably *is* hardcoded to 1000. I'd call this a bug.

Comment: @Catija Are you using the iOS App? For me, viewing vote counts in Stack Overflow always work in the iOS App as I've more than 1000 rep.

Comment: Yes... in the app... I have no issues with it on the full site.

Comment: @Catija Yup, should be a bug ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.

Vote counts aren't actually filtered in the API so this was being done naïvely in the app with a 1000 rep threshold for consistency with SO. Now the app fetches the privilege list for the given site to get the exact threshold for displaying votes.

Comment: Any chance to fix that for the android app as well? ([There is already a bug report for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261119/why-cant-i-see-the-vote-count-of-a-post-in-a-private-beta-site))

Comment: @ShadowWizard I may have fixed it for iOS only because I saw the Android bug report and knew I could fix it for iOS, then never bothered fixing it on Android.  Am I the worst?  Yes I am.

Comment: lol.. But you can nudge @Kasra, right? :-)