# Viewing votes breakdown on mobile version of the site?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, privileges, vote-count

I was really excited, cause I hit 1k on elu today, and was looking forward to seeing the breakdown of upvotes and downvotes, when I realized it doesn't seem like there's a way to do this on the mobile version of the site.

Is there a way to do this?  Or is the privilege reserved for the full desktop site.

Comment: It's certainly possible on the iOS app.

Comment: Not on the Android app as far as I can tell.

Comment: Actually, this is possible in the android app: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196839/view-number-of-up-and-down-votes-of-a-question-answer-android-app. As for mobile web, it's not possible, but you can click "full site" link in the footer, on your mobile device, and view the vote count.