# Make number of upvotes and downvotes visible on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, mobile-web, up-votes, vote-count

This was discussed [some time before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108769/245360), and I guess every using the mobile web application thinks this is a killer addition to the mobile web experience. However, this still isn't implemented.

The reason given in the old post is:

> The gotcha is that a lot of android phones really don't have the click accuracy you need to distinguish between up vote, down vote, and show vote split clicks.

Come on people. It is 2015 now. Mobile phones have gone better a lot. Also, there are other solutions at hand that could be implemented.

Can we have a second thought on this feature?

Comment: That is one of the things I miss most, when reading meta-posts on mobile. I have no idea what the community thinks, after all +5 net score isn't just +5 | -0...

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow: I totally agree. I often switch to the app, just to see the vote count on posts. Then I return to the mobile web site...

Comment: I suggest we make it a necessary feature for all devices, including computers. They could just show something like '5 (=7-2)' for all posts instead of showing just 5 and expecting you to click to see the vote count.

Comment: Not sure about that. There is a reason the number isn't shown by opening the page (performance mainly). It may also bloat the UI.