# Show vote counts on the mobile website

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes, mobile-web

I have noticed that when I'm using the Stack Overflow mobile website, it is impossible to tap number of votes to get more details about it (upvotes & downvotes).

I don't know if this feature is not implemented, or the size of votes count element is too small to be tapped.

Comment: +1 - Devs, please implement this. It is really annoying to have to switch to full site or to the android app just to see the vote count.

Comment: Should be on Meta Stack Exchange, not here. All SE Mobile sites use the same template.

Comment: We should rather just forget the mobile site altogether. The desktop site is more than usable on mobiles and can be even better by making it responsive.

Answer (score 25):

It isn't implemented yet, so you don't have to worry about your tapping skills.

I agree this is a very useful addition, something I have been wanting for a long time. Both mobile apps seem to have this, but the mobile web interface doesn't.

This feature request has been [rejected some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108769/245360), but [I brought it up on Meta SE again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251522/245360). Let's see if it helps.

Comment: You shouldn't really be starting cross-site dupes, especially when it's likely this question will be migrated to Meta SE anyway.

Comment: Sorry. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Another point though: on MSE this would most likely be closed as a duplicate of the referenced old question, while I argue the reasons mentioned in that post. You are right that in fact this shouldn't be done usually.

Answer (score 7):

I should point out that it does work if you use the mobile apps (iOS at least, and i'm pretty sure with Android too). There, long tap on the score to see the breakup.

So, as long as you're on mobile, you might as well use the native app that does include this (and some other) features. Push notifications for your inbox anyone? ;)

Comment: The mobile app misses the agility to switch between questions and sites quickly. That forces me to use the browser.

Comment: @PatrickHofman On android lollipop, switching browser tabs is the same operation as switching apps. So using chrome and the app is just as convenient as using just chrome. And push notifications are *awesome*