# Does voting count work on mobile site of stackoverflow?

Tags: support

I have gotten the ["see vote counts" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) on Stack Overflow, and I visited a lot of downvoted and upvoted posts on Stack Overflow on the mobile site, but I can't see number of upvotes and downvotes.

Does the mobile site not support it?

Comment: No the mobile view does not support showing vote splits.

Comment: No, they do not! I know this, after much clicking, pinching, accidental voting, zooming, clicking, etc. I also tried other possibilities, such as smashing my fist on the screen, and talking abruptly to my phone with some pretty serious threats, some including water... but even after a dam good thrashing I realised it's the sites designed like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mobile site does not support it. Early versions of the app [did support it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111090/167443) (might have just been development versions), but a lot of phones at the time didn't provide enough accuracy on the touchscreen to make it useful (I asked this same question several years ago).

Perhaps now that a lot of phones have larger screens, this feature may be more feasible...

Comment: The Android app definitely supports the feature, since I can view vote counts.

Comment: The iOS app also definitely supports viewing vote counts.