# Are mobile browsers still too inaccurate to show vote counts?

Tags: support, mobile-web, vote-count

Right now vote counts are not shown on the mobile theme.

I read from an old post [show vote count on the mobile theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/show-the-number-of-up-votes-and-down-votes-on-the-mobile-site-theme), that is was because some old mobile browsers were too inaccurate.

An answer to that post says:

> The gotcha is that a lot of android phones really don't have the click accuracy you need to distinguish between up vote, down vote, and show vote split clicks. It's really quite frustrating trying to vote and accidentally displaying votes or vice versus.
>
> Since it's such low priority information, I pulled it. We might revisit this when the balance of android browsers shifts, I hear through the grape vine it's gotten a lot better in the latest and greatest versions. Still too many old ones out there right now though.

That was written in 2011 and now we’re almost in 2020. Does this still apply?

It would be cool to have that feature on the phone.

Comment: The mobile skin is soon to be entirely dropped, AFAIK. The site is moving towards a responsive design that works across all platforms.

Comment: Mobile web as a whole is deprecated these days, replaced with responsive design. So I'd say it's not worth the time to develop new things or fix non-critical bugs in it. That said, switching something from hidden to visible can be instant change.

Comment: @Mithical Ok, that sounds really cool. I’m one of those who use the mobile a lot for SE, so viewing vote count, would be pretty helpful.

Comment: @Jdrupal so just use the full site, and make sure you didn't disable responsive design by clicking "Disable Responsiveness" in the footer by mistake. (Or not mistake)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not just Android; the mobile web version doesn't have this feature on iOS either. You can get the mobile version on your desktop browser too, by clicking the 'Mobile' link in the [footer](/#footer), and then it doesn't work either.

Fortunately, the feature *is* enabled in the [new responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232), and it works on desktop, iOS and Android alike. (To switch to this design, click the 'full site' link in the footer.) Since it will soon* replace the mobile web version, I don't think it's worth posting a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

*<sub>: [6-8 somethings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I’ll retag my post! If I click Request desktop site on my IPhone it works perfect. I look forward to when it’s fully rolled out :)